# Can't seem to find my EF model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.3

This might seem like a stupid question, but I got this ASP.NET MVC 3.0 application which uses Entity Framework 4.3 and SQL Server 2008. I need to add a field to one of the tables in the database. Right now the application works 100% fine. The problem is, I can't seem to find the EDMX file in my solution to resync Entity Framework with the change I made in the database. I haven't used EF 4 yet and i'm wondering if there was a change that doesn't require me to do this anymore? Because I searched my whole hard drive for the EDMX file and it simply isn't there, but the application is working just fine. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably using Code First, which doesn't use EDMX files.

You should edit the model classes directly and use migrations.